# Best way to group scripts or styles in the Head without a div?

Tags: ajax, html, scripting, load, head

Twofold question.

Using a web template that utilizes **AJAX** for loading new pages, rather than traditional point-the-browser-to-the-url style, how would one go about adding new script or style tags to the page head as necessary?

I think using jQuery $('head').append(script); works just fine, but (and here's the second half), if I wanted to group all of the scripts that were page-dependent away from those that are universal across the site - how would I do that?

Using a `div` sounds so enticing since I could print it at the initial page render and just call 
    `$('head div.external').append(script)`, but still probably a bad idea inside the **head**.

Is there any other element or method I could use to group these? The goal being to easily remove all of them when the user navigates away from the current page. A smaller consideration is that Google Analytic instructs you to place it at the end of the head tag (I'll be honest, I don't know why being the last script matters), and I don't want my scripts to interfere. Do these even need to be in the head, could I place a div at the end of the body and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely the easiest way to do this, if it is necessary, is with classes:

```
$(script).addClass('external').appendTo('head');
```

then later:

```
$('script.external').remove();
```

I'm honestly not sure what this would achieve, however.

Comment: Hadn't thought to add classes to script tags.. I don't see why it wouldn't work, thank you!